# Creating a spiral on a sphere

Tags: modeling

I am trying to create the spiral element of the following:

[image]

I've tried different methods such as a curve modifier with a capsule shape, and using 'Curve' strokes with sculpting, but I can't get quite the same results. What would be the easiest way to get these results?

Comment: for more examples, something like this:https://www.artstation.com/artwork/qoovD

Answer (score 0):

You could begin with a spiral curve (you need to enable the  *Add Curve: Extra Objects* addon):

[image]

Convert to mesh, fill the faces:

[image]

Add an edge loop:

[image]

Move it up:

[image]

Create additional edge loops in order to round the profile:

[image]

[image]

Clean the topology:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it looks promising but the center doesn't look quite spherical enough